# Parse Wordpress like Shortcode

Tags: php

I want to parse shortcode like Wordpress with attributes:

Input:

```
[include file="header.html"]
```

I need output as array, function name "include" and attributes with values as well , any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please try my library, it's standalone and already battle-tested in production: https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode . If you need anything, let me know!

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [this function](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/get-between.htm)

```
$code = '[include file="header.html"]';
$innerCode = GetBetween($code, '[', ']');
$innerCodeParts = explode(' ', $innerCode);

$command = $innerCodeParts[0];

$attributeAndValue = $innerCodeParts[1];
$attributeParts = explode('=', $attributeAndValue);
$attribute = $attributeParts[0];
$attributeValue = str_replace('"', '', $attributeParts[1]);

echo $command . ' ' . $attribute . '=' . $attributeValue;
//this will result in include file=header.html
```

$command will be "include"

$attribute will be "file"

$attributeValue will be "header.html"

Comment: I can see error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function GetBetween() in wp_parse.php on line 4

Comment: Read the first line of my answer, you need to paste this code into your file: `function GetBetween($content,$start,$end){
    $r = explode($start, $content);
    if (isset($r[1])){
        $r = explode($end, $r[1]);
        return $r[0];
    }
    return '';
}`

Comment: @ShahzabAsif I didn't test my code so let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a utility class that we used on our project
It will match all shortcodes in a string (including html) and it will output an associative array including their `name`, `attributes` and `content`

```
final class Parser {

    // Regex101 reference: https://regex101.com/r/pJ7lO1
    const SHORTOCODE_REGEXP = "/(?P<shortcode>(?:(?:\\s?\\[))(?P<name>[\\w\\-]{3,})(?:\\s(?P<attrs>[\\w\\d,\\s=\\\"\\'\\-\\+\\#\\%\\!\\~\\`\\&\\.\\s\\:\\/\\?\\|]+))?(?:\\])(?:(?P<content>[\\w\\d\\,\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&\\*\\(\\\\)\\s\\=\\\"\\'\\-\\+\\&\\.\\s\\:\\/\\?\\|\\<\\>]+)(?:\\[\\/[\\w\\-\\_]+\\]))?)/u";

    // Regex101 reference: https://regex101.com/r/sZ7wP0
    const ATTRIBUTE_REGEXP = "/(?<name>\\S+)=[\"']?(?P<value>(?:.(?![\"']?\\s+(?:\\S+)=|[>\"']))+.)[\"']?/u";

    public static function parse_shortcodes($text) {
        preg_match_all(self::SHORTOCODE_REGEXP, $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
        $shortcodes = array();
        foreach ($matches as $i => $value) {
            $shortcodes[$i]['shortcode'] = $value['shortcode'];
            $shortcodes[$i]['name'] = $value['name'];
            if (isset($value['attrs'])) {
                $attrs = self::parse_attrs($value['attrs']);
                $shortcodes[$i]['attrs'] = $attrs;
            }
            if (isset($value['content'])) {
                $shortcodes[$i]['content'] = $value['content'];
            }
        }

        return $shortcodes;
    }

    private static function parse_attrs($attrs) {
        preg_match_all(self::ATTRIBUTE_REGEXP, $attrs, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
        $attributes = array();
        foreach ($matches as $i => $value) {
            $key = $value['name'];
            $attributes[$i][$key] = $value['value'];
        }
        return $attributes;
    }
}

print_r(Parser::parse_shortcodes('[include file="header.html"]'));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [shortcode] => [include file="header.html"]
            [name] => include
            [attrs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [file] => header.html
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: This is great.. but is there a way to do it as a replace.. it just transforms the shortcode and it removes any other text that may be around it..

Comment: @REPTILE The question requested that it will parse the shortcode and the output it as an associative array. You can then take each element and produce whatever output you like. You could do something like ```str_replace($shortcode, $compiled_shortcode, $string)``` That will search for the shortcode, and replace it with the ```$compiled_output``` that you have produced inside a string. Normally the string is the entire html like the ```post_content```

Comment: does unfortunately not work when value is only 1 char long (e.g. id=8 or id="8"). I think I fixed it: https://regex101.com/r/sZ7wP0/6

Answer (score 3):

I also needed this functionality in my PHP framework. This is what I've written, it works pretty well. It works with anonymous functions, which I really like (it's a bit like the callback functions in JavaScript).

```
<?php
//The content which should be parsed
$content = '<p>Hello, my name is John an my age is [calc-age day="4" month="10" year="1991"].</p>';
$content .= '<p>Hello, my name is Carol an my age is [calc-age day="26" month="11" year="1996"].</p>';

//The array with all the shortcode handlers. This is just a regular associative array with anonymous functions as values. A very cool new feature in PHP, just like callbacks in JavaScript or delegates in C#.
$shortcodes = array(
    "calc-age" => function($data){
        $content = "";
        //Calculate the age
        if(isset($data["day"], $data["month"], $data["year"])){
            $age = date("Y") - $data["year"];
            if(date("m") < $data["month"]){
                $age--;
            }
            if(date("m") == $data["month"] && date("d") < $data["day"]){
                $age--;
            }
            $content = $age;
        }
        return $content;
    }
);
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196159/regex-extract-variables-from-shortcode
function handleShortcodes($content, $shortcodes){
    //Loop through all shortcodes
    foreach($shortcodes as $key => $function){
        $dat = array();
        preg_match_all("/\[".$key." (.+?)\]/", $content, $dat);
        if(count($dat) > 0 && $dat[0] != array() && isset($dat[1])){
            $i = 0;
            $actual_string = $dat[0];
            foreach($dat[1] as $temp){
                $temp = explode(" ", $temp);
                $params = array();
                foreach ($temp as $d){
                    list($opt, $val) = explode("=", $d);
                    $params[$opt] = trim($val, '"');
                }
                $content = str_replace($actual_string[$i], $function($params), $content);
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
echo handleShortcodes($content, $shortcodes);
?>
```

The result:
Hello, my name is John an my age is 22.
Hello, my name is Carol an my age is 17.

Comment: Great piece of code - thanks! I did notice that if you change the explode like to $temp = explode('" ', $temp); then you can have spaces in the quoted values.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually tougher than it might appear on the surface. Andrew's answer works, but begins to break down if square brackets appear in the source text [like this, for example]. WordPress works by pre-registering a list of valid shortcodes, and only acting on text inside brackets if it matches one of these predefined values. That way it doesn't mangle any regular text that might just happen to have a set of square brackets in it.

The actual [source code](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/shortcodes.php) of the WordPress shortcode engine is fairly robust, and it doesn't look like it would be all that tough to modify the file to run by itself -- then you could use that in your application to handle the tough work. (If you're interested, take a look at `get_shortcode_regex()` in that file to see just how hairy the proper solution to this problem can actually get.)

A very rough implementation of your question using the WP shortcodes.php would look **something** like:

```
// Define the shortcode
function inlude_shortcode_func($attrs) {
    $data = shortcode_atts(array(
        'file' => 'default'
    ), $attrs);

    return "Including File: {$data['file']}";
}
add_shortcode('include', 'inlude_shortcode_func');

// And then run your page content through the filter
echo do_shortcode('This is a document with [include file="header.html"] included!');
```

Again, not tested at all, but it's not a very hard API to use.

Comment: It would have been better if you would have included a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the @Duco's snippet, As it seems like, it's exploding by spaces which ruins when we have some like

```
[Image source="myimage.jpg" alt="My Image"]
```

To current one:

```
function handleShortcodes($content, $shortcodes){
    function read_attr($attr) {
        $atList = [];

        if (preg_match_all('/\s*(?:([a-z0-9-]+)\s*=\s*"([^"]*)")|(?:\s+([a-z0-9-]+)(?=\s*|>|\s+[a..z0-9]+))/i', $attr, $m)) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($m[0]); $i++) {
                if ($m[3][$i])
                    $atList[$m[3][$i]] = null;
                else
                    $atList[$m[1][$i]] = $m[2][$i];
            }
        }
        return $atList;
    }
    //Loop through all shortcodes
    foreach($shortcodes as $key => $function){
        $dat = array();
        preg_match_all("/\[".$key."(.*?)\]/", $content, $dat);

        if(count($dat) > 0 && $dat[0] != array() && isset($dat[1])){
            $i = 0;
            $actual_string = $dat[0];
            foreach($dat[1] as $temp){
                $params = read_attr($temp);
                $content = str_replace($actual_string[$i], $function($params), $content);
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
$content = '[image source="one" alt="one two"]';
```

Result:

```
array( 
  [source] => myimage.jpg,
  [alt] => My Image
)
```

**Updated (Feb 11, 2020)**
It appears to be following regex under preg_match only identifies shortcode with attributes

```
preg_match_all("/\[".$key." (.+?)\]/", $content, $dat);
```

to make it work with as normal **[contact-form]** or **[mynotes]**. We can change the following to

```
preg_match_all("/\[".$key."(.*?)\]/", $content, $dat);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified above function with wordpress function

```
function extractThis($short_code_string) {
    $shortocode_regexp = "/(?P<shortcode>(?:(?:\\s?\\[))(?P<name>[\\w\\-]{3,})(?:\\s(?P<attrs>[\\w\\d,\\s=\\\"\\'\\-\\+\\#\\%\\!\\~\\`\\&\\.\\s\\:\\/\\?\\|]+))?(?:\\])(?:(?P<content>[\\w\\d\\,\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&\\*\\(\\\\)\\s\\=\\\"\\'\\-\\+\\&\\.\\s\\:\\/\\?\\|\\<\\>]+)(?:\\[\\/[\\w\\-\\_]+\\]))?)/u";
    preg_match_all($shortocode_regexp, $short_code_string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    $shortcodes = array();
    foreach ($matches as $i => $value) {
       $shortcodes[$i]['shortcode'] = $value['shortcode'];
       $shortcodes[$i]['name'] = $value['name'];
       if (isset($value['attrs'])) {
        $attrs = shortcode_parse_atts($value['attrs']);
        $shortcodes[$i]['attrs'] = $attrs;
       }
       if (isset($value['content'])) {
        $shortcodes[$i]['content'] = $value['content'];
       }
    }
    return $shortcodes;
  }
```

I think this one help for all :)

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem.  For what I have to do, I am going to take advantage of existing xml parsers instead of writing my own regex.  I am sure there are cases where it won't work

example.php

```
<?php

$file_content = '[include file="header.html"]';

// convert the string into xml
$xml = str_replace("[", "<", str_replace("]", "/>", $file_content));

$doc = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

echo "name: " . $doc->getName() . "\n";
foreach($doc->attributes() as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: $value\n";
}
```

```
$ php example.php 
name: include
file: header.html
```

to make it work on ubuntu I think you have to do this

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
```

(thanks https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/218271)

If you have lots of these strings in a file, then I think you can still do the find replace, and then just treat it all like xml.