# PHP: Use preg_match_all to create objects and call object functions

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I'm trying to use preg_match_all to find instances of a pattern in text, then use that pattern to instantiate a class and finally call a class function to print replacement text for the matching pattern. I don't know if I'm going about it the right way.

I can find and replace this pattern [bandcamp=http://bandcamp-page.com]1[/bandcamp] with this preg_replace function

```
$text = preg_replace ("/\[bandcamp=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/bandcamp\]/", "replacement text here", $text);
```

But I want to use the matches to create a BandcampAlbum object and call it's player() function which prints out html. This is what I'm trying but to no avail so far.

```
if (preg_match_all ("/\[bandcamp=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/bandcamp\]/", $text, $matches)) {

    foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
        preg_replace ("/\[bandcamp=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/bandcamp\]/", "", $text);
        $bc = new BandcampAlbum($match[0], $match[1]);
        $bc->player();
    }

}
```

The preg_replace in the foreach loop is intended to just get rid of the matching text. The matching seems to work so I'm guessing I'm doing it the wrong way rather than making a regular expression error.  Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: You are inquiring for [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback), which allows to instantiate your object and pass its result right in place of the pattern.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18196595/2364629 shows an example of using preg_replace_callback for this

Comment: Thanks guys. @Orangepill, in your example there the processShortCode function is already defined and to hand, and you can drop it into the preg_replace_callback as the second parameter. However, I'm trying to use the regular expression to get the data I need to instantiate an object and the function I want to use is defined in the object class so I don't think I can just pass it in to the preg_replace_callback as it doesn't exist yet. Does that sound right? I'm not sure I'm getting the way preg_replace_callback is suppose to work.

Comment: You would just use the values gotten from the capture groups in the pattern that you specified to map to a particular class (either via a class map or through inflection). You can also use those values to pass in any of the parameters needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments; what you are probably after is [preg_replace_callback](http://www.php.net/preg-replace-callback). Here is an example of its usage with your problem:

```
function getBandCampMarkup($matches){
    $bc = new BandcampAction($matches[1], $matches[2]);
    return $bc->player();
}

$data = preg_replace_callback("/\[bandcamp=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/bandcamp\]/", "getBandCampMarkup", $data);
echo $data;
```

This is of course assuming the `$bc->player()` returns a string of the output. If this function just echos the data then you can can use `ob_start` and `ob_get_clean` to capture the output as a string as so:

```
ob_start();
$bc->player();
return ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: That works (mostly - one player in the right place, two in the wrong, but that's another matter) and makes sense to me now. Thanks a million @Orangepill :-)