# Preg_Split is not keeping the delimeter

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I'm trying to parse the attributes out of a shortcode tag that I have.  The string that I'm starting with looks like this.

```
href="https://example.com" class="bootstrap class names"
```

I'm using this expression, which gets me ALMOST there.

```
$attribute_dna = '/"\s/';
$attributes = preg_split($attribute_dna, $attributes_string, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

the output I get is this...

```
string(27) "href="https://example.com"  <--Problem is right here (missing a quote)
string(17) "class="bootstrap class names""
```

You can see above if i had the ending quote on the href just like the second one it would be perfect.  But it's not capturing the delimeter.

I'd appreciate any and all help I can get.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may use [`'/\s+(?=\w+=["\'])/'`](https://ideone.com/NWo640).

Comment: Split on `(?<=")\s+(?=\S)` but I would suggest you use an XML parser instead. It seems you're getting attributes from an HTML tag, just use a parser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse Wordpress like Shortcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735258/parse-wordpress-like-shortcode)

Comment: @ctwheels yes, he should use an library to use this, but thats not the question he asked. Btw - the linked duplicate answer is of poor quality..

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this much more beautiful?

```
<?php

$html = <<<DATA
<div>
    <a href="https://example.com" class="bootstrap class names">Some link here</a>
</div>
DATA;

# set up the DOM
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);

# set up the xpath
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->query("//a") as $link) {
    foreach ($link->attributes as $attr) {
        $name = $attr->nodeName;
        $value = $attr->nodeValue;
        echo "Attribute '$name': '$value'\n";
    }
}
?>
```

Which yields

```
Attribute 'href': 'https://example.com'
Attribute 'class': 'bootstrap class names'
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This is the proper way to parse XML or HTML. You don't use regex to do this.

Comment: It doesn't look like OP has html but some short code as noted in the question

Comment: @PeeHaa `I'm trying to parse the attributes out of a shortcode tag` - clearly the OP is trying to do just that.

Comment: @ctwheels: I guess so, too.

Comment: Even if OP has HTML (which is a big assumption on your end) xpath is not needed for what you are doing

Comment: Well if that's the case, the OP shouldn't be reinventing the wheel. There are existing parsers out there for just this type of thing https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode

Comment: Yes OP should. I agree. But that isn't my issue with this answer.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm marking this question as a duplicate then, there's another question that resembles this.

Comment: @PeeHaa: Right you are, an `xpath` expression might be a little overkill here. Was just filtering out the anchor tags in question.