# Get shortcode attribute form wordpress post content

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, shortcode

I Have a shortcode in post content:
`[restrict paid="true"][download id='1234'][/restrict]`

I need to extract 1234 value from the shortcode.
I use this funtion but it not work:

```
function get_download_ids( $content, $shortcode ) {
    $pattern = get_shortcode_regex();
    $ids = array();

    // Find download shortcodes.
    if (   preg_match_all( '/'. $pattern .'/s', $content, $matches ) &&
           array_key_exists( 2, $matches ) &&
           in_array( $shortcode, $matches[2] ) )
    {
        foreach( $matches[2] as $shortcode_index => $shortcode_name ) {
            if ( $shortcode_name === $shortcode ) {
                $shortcode_str = $matches[0][ $shortcode_index ];

                // Extract shortcode attributes.
                $shortcode_attrs_str = str_replace( $shortcode, '', $shortcode_str );
                $shortcode_attrs_str = trim( $shortcode_attrs_str, '[]' );

                // Convert attributes into array.
                $atts = shortcode_parse_atts( $shortcode_attrs_str );

                if ( ! empty( $atts['id'] ) ) {
                    $ids[] = $atts['id'];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return array_unique( $ids );
}
```

Look forward to the help of everyone.
Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Parse Wordpress like Shortcode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15735258)

Comment: Since this is a nested shortcode, this might be helpful: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/406729/12496